# Find nearest next date based on first row date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgresql db as follows:

```
sl_no | valid_from | 
--------------------
  1      02-04-2013
  2      02-09-2012
  3      02-11-2015
  4      02-01-2011
  5      02-10-2015
```

I want to get all rows `orderby` valid_from and along with one dummy column name as valid_to. Here, values of valid_to should come from the nearest next date of every valid_from value.

Something like below:

```
sl_no | valid_from | valid_to |
---------------------------------
  4      02-01-2011  02-09-2012
  2      02-09-2012  02-04-2013
  1      02-04-2013  02-10-2015
  5      02-10-2015  02-11-2015 
  3      02-11-2015  02-11-2015
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lead()` will do that:

```
select sl_no, valid_from, 
       lead(valid_from, 1, valid_from) over (order by valid_from) as valid_to
from the_table
order by valid_from;
```

`lead()` picks the column value of specified column of the *next* row (defined by the `order by`). The parameters `1, valid_from` specify that the database should look 1 row ahead and in case there is no such row, the third parameter is returned. `lead(valid_from)` is a short form of `lead(valid_from, 1, null)`.

Set the manual for details:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

SQLFiddle examle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/61d53/1